# Colored copy of PuTTY window

Tags: colors, console, putty

I need to copy colored text from PuTTY window without losing color information. Console is in UTF-8 mode. What is the best method? Any parsable output will do.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Change Settings... > Window / Selection

At the bottom of the PuTTY Configuration dialog is a section "Formatting of pasted characters".
Tick the checkbox for **Paste to clipboard in RTF as well as plain text**,

Click <kbd>Apply</kbd>, then select your text and paste it somewhere.

Answer (score 7):

Looks like this option has moved to a submenu since the answer was posted in 2010.

In 2020, I have Putty Release 0.74:

Window->selection->copy->Copy to clipboard in RTF as well as plain text
[image: Animated GIF showing steps]

Comment: Also be aware that you need to restart a Putty session for this setting to work.